# Python save variable to file like save() in MATLAB

Tags: python-2.7

I just new in python. How to save variable data to file like save command in MATLAB.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx TheBlackCat

Example my code

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle  # Improve speed
except ValueError:
    import pickle

file_temp = open('temp', 'w')
pickle.dump(scenes, file_temp)
file_temp.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pickle.dump` in Python 3.x, or `cPickle.dump` in Python 2.x.