# Export lists and variables in a txt file and import them in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and would like to export some nested lists and some variables in a .txt file in python, and to be able to retrieve these data and to import them later in python.

For instance,

```
my_list1 =  [[[-1, 1, 0, -1]], [[-1, 1, 0, -1]]]
my_list2 =   [[[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 2]], [[2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1]]]
my_var = 3
my_var2 = 7
```

I tried

```
   with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
      for ( my_list1 , my_list2) in zip(my_list1 , my_list2 ):
         f.write("{1},{2}\n".format(my_list1 , my_list2))
```

but I don't know how to also export my variables with it, and how to import and retrieve each data after.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python save variable to file like save() in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915120/python-save-variable-to-file-like-save-in-matlab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python serialization - Why pickle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968884/python-serialization-why-pickle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

```
import pickle

my_list1 =  [[[-1, 1, 0, -1]], [[-1, 1, 0, -1]]]
my_list2 =   [[[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 2]], [[2, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1, 1]]]
my_var = 3
my_var2 = 7

# storing to file
with open("file.txt", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump((my_list1, my_list2, my_var, my_var2), f)

# loading from file
with open("file.txt", 'rb') as f:
    retrived_list1, retrived_list2, retrived_var, retrived_var2 = pickle.load(f)

print(retrived_list1 == my_list1, retrived_list2 == my_list2, retrived_var == my_var, retrived_var2 == my_var2)
```

Output:`True True True True`